# How to write a module that works with Node.js, RequireJS as well as without them

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I am working on a JavaScript library for [JSON/XML processing](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix). My library works in browser as well as Node.js (with `xmldom` and `xmlhttprequest` modules).

One of the users recently asked for RequireJS support. I have taken a look at the RequireJS/AMD thing and think it is a good approach so I'd like to provide this.

However I'd like to retain the portability: my library must work in browsers (with and without RequireJS) as well as Node.js. And in the browser environment I don't depend on `xmldom` or `xmlhttprequest` since these things are provided by the browser itself.

**My question is: how can I implement my library so that it works in browsers as well as in Node.js with an without RequireJS?**

A bit of historyand my current solution

I initially wrote my library for browsers. So it just created a global-scope object and put everything inside it:

```
var Jsonix = { ... };
```

Later on users asked for Node.js support. So I added:

```
if(typeof require === 'function'){
    module.exports.Jsonix = Jsonix;
}
```

I also had to import few modules mentioned above. I did it conditionally, depending on whether the `require` function is available or not:

```
if (typeof require === 'function')
{
    var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Now there's this story with RequireJS. If RequireJS is present then the `require` function is present as well. But module loading works differently, I have to use the `define` function etc. I also can't just `require` things since `require` has an async API in RequireJS. Moreover, if my library is loaded via RequireJS, it seems to process the source code and detects `require('something')` even if I do it conditionally like

```
if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof require.specified !== 'function) ...
```

RequireJS still detects `require('xmlhttprequest')` an tries to load the corresponding JS file.

Currently I'm coming to the following solution.

```
// Module factory function, AMD style
var _jsonix = function(_jsonix_xmldom, _jsonix_xmlhttprequest, _jsonix_fs)
{
    // Complete Jsonix script is included below 
    var Jsonix = { ... };
    // Complete Jsonix script is included above
    return { Jsonix: Jsonix };
};

// If require function exists ...
if (typeof require === 'function') {
    // ... but define function does not exists, assume we're in the Node.js environment
    // In this case, load the define function via amdefine
    if (typeof define !== 'function') {
        var define = require('amdefine')(module);
        define(["xmldom", "xmlhttprequest", "fs"], _jsonix);
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise assume we're in the RequireJS environment
        define([], _jsonix);
    }
}
// Since require function does not exists,
// assume we're neither in Node.js nor in RequireJS environment
// This is probably a browser environment
else
{
    // Call the module factory directly
    var Jsonix = _jsonix();
}
```

And this is how I check for dependencies now:

```
if (typeof _jsonix_xmlhttprequest !== 'undefined')
{
    var XMLHttpRequest = _jsonix_xmlhttprequest.XMLHttpRequest;
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

If I have `require` but not `define` then I assume this is a Node.js environment. I use `amdefine` to define the module and pass the required dependencies.

If I have `require` and `define` thet I assume this is a RequireJS environment, so I just use the `define` function. Currently I also assume this is a browser environment so dependencies like `xmldom` and `xmlhttprequest` are not available and don't require them. (This is probably nor correct.)

If I don't have the `require` function then I assume this is a browser environment without RequireJS/AMD support so I invoke the module factory `_jsonix` directly and export the result as a global object.

So, this is my approach so far. Seems a little bit awkward to me, and as a newbie to RequireJS/AMD I'm seeking advise. Is it the right approach? Are there better ways to address the problem? I'd be grateful for your help.

Comment: this may be useful: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at how [underscore.js](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) handles it.

```
// Export the Underscore object for **Node.js**, with
// backwards-compatibility for the old `require()` API. If we're in
// the browser, add `_` as a global object.
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    exports = module.exports = _;
  }
  exports._ = _;
} else {
  root._ = _;
}
```

...

```
// AMD registration happens at the end for compatibility with AMD loaders
// that may not enforce next-turn semantics on modules. Even though general
// practice for AMD registration is to be anonymous, underscore registers
// as a named module because, like jQuery, it is a base library that is
// popular enough to be bundled in a third party lib, but not be part of
// an AMD load request. Those cases could generate an error when an
// anonymous define() is called outside of a loader request.
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define('underscore', [], function() {
    return _;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I ended up with:

```
// If the require function exists ...
if (typeof require === 'function') {
    // ... but the define function does not exists
    if (typeof define !== 'function') {
        // Assume we're in the Node.js environment
        // In this case, load the define function via amdefine
        var define = require('amdefine')(module);
        // Use xmldom and xmlhttprequests as dependencies
        define(["xmldom", "xmlhttprequest", "fs"], _jsonix_factory);
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise assume we're in the browser/RequireJS environment
        // Load the module without xmldom and xmlhttprequests dependencies
        define([], _jsonix_factory);
    }
}
// If the require function does not exists, we're not in Node.js and therefore in browser environment
else
{
    // Just call the factory and set Jsonix as global.
    var Jsonix = _jsonix_factory().Jsonix;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a template I'm currently using, it's both AMD and node compatible though not directly loadable stand-alone in the browser...

The main advantage to this approach is that the domain-specific code does not need to care about what imported it, for the general case.

```
/**********************************************************************
* 
*
*
**********************************************************************/
((typeof define)[0]=='u'?function(f){module.exports=f(require)}:define)(
function(require){ var module={} // makes module AMD/node compatible...
/*********************************************************************/




/*********************************************************************/




/**********************************************************************
* vim:set ts=4 sw=4 :                               */ return module })
```