# Make a JS library happy with Node and Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, npm

I maintain [a JS library](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) that I'd like to make into a Node module, and use with Node.

My library extends the Canvas context API and requires `getImageData()`, and so starts with this defensive line wrapping all code:

```
if (window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData){
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.blendOnto = /* … */;
}
```

With Node, I am using [Node Canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas). To get my existing code to work, I need to write Node code like this:

```
var Canvas = require('canvas');
GLOBAL.CanvasRenderingContext2D = Canvas.Context2d;
GLOBAL.window = GLOBAL;
require('context_blender');
```

This appears to be clearly fighting Node's module pattern, however. How can I best rewrite my library and package it as a node module so that it (a) continues to work in a web browser, but (b) cleanly works with Node Canvas, without having to pass data through globals? Is there a way to pass the `Canvas.Context2d` to my module to mutate?

Comment: My current thought is to create a second `.js` file just for node, and export a function that basically does the above for you when you pass it an object, i.e. `var Canvas = require('canvas'); require('context-blender')(Canvas.Context2d);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274930/how-to-write-a-module-that-works-with-node-js-requirejs-as-well-as-without-them

Comment: Did you consider to use browserify?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak No, for I had not heard of Browserify before you mentioned it. It does not look appropriate to my needs, because the Node version of my library uses node-canvas, but I do not need or want that in the web browser.

Comment: browserify and node both use commonJs module's scheme. If you extract canvas dependency to a separate module (actually modules), then you can create different canvas' module for node environment and different for browser environment. Then basically you have two options: either create different bundles for node and browser or check at runtime the environment and require your dependency accordingly.

Comment: you should abstract the parts that change so you're main code body can remains the same, and a small interface adapter customizes it for each environment. look into "dependency injection" for good reasons to consider the approach.

Comment: Here's anothe thing I've found: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend putting your code in a module factory function like this:

```
var context_blender_factory = function(CanvasRenderingContext2D)
{
    var defaultOffsets = {
        // ...
    };
    // Applies to the parameter passed to the module factory function  
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.blendOnto = // ...
    // ...
}
```

This essentially abstracts away *where* do you get your `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

Then, after declaring your function you could write the initialization routine where you check your environment and call the module factory accordingly.

If you just want to consider pure NodeJS, this would be something like:

```
if (typeof require === 'function') {
    // Assume NodeJS environment
    context_blender_factory(require('canvas').Context2d);
}
else if (window &&
         window.CanvasRenderingContext2D &&
         window.CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData)
{
    // Assume browser environment
    context_blender_factory(window.CanvasRenderingContext2D);
}
```

This pattern would also allow supporting [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)-style module environments like 
[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [amdefine](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine).

---

**Backstory**

I had a similar situation with [my JS library](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) (see the backstory below).

I have initially implemented my library for the browser.

Then people started asking if it could work in NodeJS. That was not hard at all as Node had all the relevant modules to mimic/implement functions just as in browser. So I have added `require`/`export` constructs for NodeJS.

Then some other people started asking about [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)/[AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)-style module support. I have asked around:

> [How to write a module that works with Node.js, RequireJS as well as without them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274930/how-to-write-a-module-that-works-with-node-js-requirejs-as-well-as-without-them)

And finally arrived to the [following solution](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/81bc54fc5b1abe90a478cf92ff75686342763996/scripts/src/main/javascript/org/hisrc/jsonix/Jsonix/Jsonix.footer.fragmentjs#L5-L26) to support browser, NodeJS, RequiredJS/AMD/amdefine.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and experience. I'm going to leave this open a few more days to see if any alternative views come along, but this certainly seems reasonable.

Comment: @Phrogz Don't accept the answer yet then. I am also interested in more answers so I'll put a bounty on the question.

Comment: +1 I’d endorse  lexicore’s factory pattern that injects .Context2d or .CanvasRenderingContext2D based on duck typing the environment.  Here’s an alternative detection test (we “borrowed” from Underscore.js): `var isInNode=(typeof exports !== 'undefined') && (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports);`

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice to provide *separate* builds for node and the browser. Why would you need node-related code in the browser and vise versa?

So I propose you prepend your code with

```
var RenderingContext2d = require('Canvas').Context2d
```

Then use `RenderingContext2d` for everything you need, and when you create a build for a browser replace `require('Canvas').Context2d` with `window.CanvasRenderingContext2D` (which is easily automated with sed and many other tools).

As a result you'd get

- no node-related code in the browser build;
- no browser-related code in the node build;
- instantly working code for node to reference in package.json "main" directive;
- a tautological assignment which a smart enough JavaScript minifier would inline into your code — a good thing for the browser.

Comment: Do you happen to have any references for the "common practice to provide *separate* builds for node and the browser"?

Comment: Sure. For example, Mocha has a browser build (https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/mocha.js) and a node build (https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha.js).

This is a node ("main") and browser directives in their package.json: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/package.json#L32-L33

Comment: For that regard any NPM package with both "browser" and a "main" directives having different value in package.json

Comment: Bounty for the different - and valid approach. Not quite suitable for my own purposes, but a valid way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it similarly to lexicore with, however, some differences. The entire thing should be in an anonymous function (like the library does now), and I would perform the test differently. On the basis of the code that already exists in the the JS library, I'd do:

```
(function () {
    var defaultOffsets = {
    // ....
    };

    function addBlendMethod(object) {
        // This should not need to change from that it is now.
    }

    function blendOnto(...
    // ... etc ...

    // At the end of the anonymous function, test the environment
    // and act accordingly.
    if (typeof require === 'function' &&
       !(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)) {
        // Node...
        addBlendMethod(require('canvas').Context2d.prototype);
    }
    else {
        addBlendMethod(window.CanvasRenderingContext2D &&
                       window.CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype);
    }
})();
```

The check for `!(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)` is necessary to avoid getting a false positive on the Node check. If someone tries to load your code in a browser, *and* RequireJS (or another AMD-compatible loader) is already present, and the check is only for `require`, your code would try to `require('canvas')` and would fail. That's because RequireJS defines `require` too. The `define` check prevents this false positive. An AMD-compatible loader is supposed to define the `define` function and set an `amd` property on it. The problem the absence of the check could cause is not just hypothetical. Once in a while someone posts a RequireJS question on SO about how library so-and-so fails to load with RequireJS and I have to answer that the environment detection code in the library is buggy because it figures it is running in Node.

Contrarily to the code currently in the library, I use `window` rather than `this`. I prefer not to rely on the behavior of non-strict code that sets `this` to `window` when it is otherwise unspecified. It can lead to breakage in some conditions, and I've never encountered a condition where relying on this behavior was *required*.

Comment: The reason I do a named module factory function is that it is easier to handle later on. Check the environment and then call it either via AMD (RequireJS/amdefine) `define` OR load dependencies via NodeJS `require` and pass them to that module factory function OR call it directory (browser with no environment). Naming the module factory function makes it much more versatile.

Comment: This is my [environment detection code](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/81bc54fc5b1abe90a478cf92ff75686342763996/scripts/src/main/javascript/org/hisrc/jsonix/Jsonix/Jsonix.footer.fragmentjs#L6-L26), I think this wouldn't be possible otherwise.